# C# Compiler Optimising Loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to control access to an object so that it may only be accessed a certain number of times over a given timespan. In one unit test that I have, access is limit to once per second. So 5 accesses should take just over 4 seconds. However, the test is failing on our TFS server, taking only 2 seconds. A stripped down version of my code to do this is here:

```
public class RateLimitedSessionStrippedDown<T>
{
    private readonly int _rateLimit;
    private readonly TimeSpan _rateLimitSpan;
    private readonly T _instance;
    private readonly object _lock;

    private DateTime _lastReset;
    private DateTime _lastUse;
    private int _retrievalsSinceLastReset;

    public RateLimitedSessionStrippedDown(int limitAmount, TimeSpan limitSpan, T instance )
    {
        _rateLimit = limitAmount;
        _rateLimitSpan = limitSpan;
        _lastUse = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _instance = instance;
        _lock = new object();
    }

    private void IncreaseRetrievalCount()
    {
        _retrievalsSinceLastReset++;
    }

    public T GetRateLimitedSession()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _lastUse = DateTime.UtcNow;

            Block();

            IncreaseRetrievalCount();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void Block()
    {
        while (_retrievalsSinceLastReset >= _rateLimit &&
           _lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan) > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
        }

        if (DateTime.UtcNow > _lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan))
        {
            _lastReset = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _retrievalsSinceLastReset = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

While running on my computer, in both Debug and Release, it works fine. However, I have a unit test that fails once I commit to our TFS build server. This is the test:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestRateLimitOnePerSecond_AssertTakesAtLeastNMinusOneSeconds()
    {
        var rateLimiter = new RateLimitedSessionStrippedDown<object>(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new object());

        DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            rateLimiter.GetRateLimitedSession();
        }

        DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;

        Assert.GreaterOrEqual(end.Subtract(start), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    }
```

[image: Test failure from the TFS CI Build Server]

I wonder if the loop in the test is being optimised in a way that it runs each iteration of the loop on a separate thread (or something similar), which means that the test completes quicker than it should because Thread.Sleep only blocks the thread that it is being called on?

Comment: There are some odd things about the code -- such as, I don't see why you have `_lastUse`, and it would be better to use `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow` to track time -- but I don't see anything obviously wrong that would explain the problem. The only thing that comes to mind is the possibility that (since you're not using `Stopwatch`), if the system time fails to get updated for some reason, the clock time will incorrectly measure the actual elapsed time. It's _highly_ unlikely this has anything to do with a compiler optimization, particularly one involving threading.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens when `_lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan) == DateTime.UtcNow`. Also, for this otherwise well written code it is curious and opaque to rely on  the `_lastReset = default(DateTime)` initialization. Also, real code shouldn't `Sleep()`. Consider waiting on a Waithandle or something.

Comment: An unlikely but definitely theoretically possible way for this test to fail is if synchronisation with a time server takes place while you're running your test (and you have no control over that). It would be very surprising to me if this is actually the problem, though.

Comment: Something very strange is happening - I made a change on another part of the same project, committed the code, and all tests passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is inside of the `Block` method, and now that I look at the comments, it appears that Henk Holterman has already brought this up.

It will only fail when `_lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan)` and `DateTime.UtcNow` are equal. This doesn't happen very often, hence the reason why it fails intermittently. A fix would be to change `>` to `>=` on this line:

```
if (DateTime.UtcNow > _lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan))
```

It's not intuitive why, unless you understand that each call to `DateTime.UtcNow` doesn't necessarily return a new value one each call.

Even though `DateTime.UtcNow` is precise up to **100 nanoseconds**, its precision is not the same as its accuracy. It relies on the machine's timer interval, which ranges from 1-15ms, but more often set to 15.25ms, unless you're doing something with multimedia.

You can see this in action with this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gjOySb). Unless you have a program open that is setting the timer to a different value, like 1ms, you'll notice that the difference between the ticks is about 150000 ticks, about 15ms, or the normal system timer interval.

We can also validate this by lifting out the calls to `DateTime.UtcNow` into temporary variables and comparing them at the end of the method:

```
    private void Block()
    {
        var first = DateTime.UtcNow;
        while (_retrievalsSinceLastReset >= _rateLimit &&
           _lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan) > first)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
            first = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        var second = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (second > _lastReset.Add(_rateLimitSpan))
        {
            _lastReset = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _retrievalsSinceLastReset = 0;
        }

        if (first == second)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DateTime.UtcNow returned same value");
        }
    }
```

On my machine, all five calls to `Block` printed out `DateTime.UtcNow` as being equal.